# How to get two class objects from on PFQuery in ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

In my application i am using parse sdk. In parse sdk databrowser i have two classes.

ClassA and ClassB .

Both classes are independent. they dont have any relation. I want to write a single query which gets objects from both classes in one array.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Parse SDK (1.2.12) does not provide such feature right out of the box.
The PFQuery Class only provides methods such as queryWithClassName: limited to one Class at a time.
You have to create and execute two separate PFQuery.

Answer (score 0):

DBar is right.  You can not download two different classes with the same query.

My solution was to make one universal class with a "type" field that I could use to parse out which class it should belong to on the user end.  That way I could combine the two queries and sort out which belongs to which class on the user end.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Join Table

Class C which includes both Class A and Class B

so with just one query you can fetch both Class A and Class B
using includeKey.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassC"];
[query includeKey:@"classAObject"];
[query includeKey:@"classBObject"];

NSArray * results = [query find];
```